# Authentication required by Wifi network Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, 14.04, authentication, gnome-keyring

Whenever I connect to my Wifi network, this annoying "authentication required by Wifi network" window pops up, with my wWifi password in it. All I have to do is to press the Connect button. Still I think this is an incorrect behavior, and I'd like to know if there is a fix.
Please note that I have "Allow all users to connect" checked and "Connect automatically" checked too. My network adapter is a Broadcom one, and is using a proprietary driver, which I enabled from Additional Drivers. The system is a fresh install.

Comment: Remove all connections from network manager and restart then let network manager find your connection itself and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Same here; happens on all networks I connect to

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the box next to *MTU* in the **Wifi Configuration** menu so *Automatic* is selected:

Click on **Wifi panel indicator > edit > select the network you want > edit > wifi**; *MTU* is at the bottom of the window.

Comment: apparently this got fixed sometime down the road. So not happening now

Comment: I don't see the MTU option under my wifi connections. I only see the MTU option under my wired connection.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by connecting from network directly. go to system settings -> network -> wireless then connect to your network. I hop it will be fixed.

Comment: I don't see any wireless option under Settings | Network